homomorphism between projectives factors through radical
Let $A$ be an hereditary finite dimensional k-Algebra and let $\phi: P \to Q$ be a nonzero Homomorphism between indecomposable projective $A$- Modules. Show that $\phi$ factors through $rad Q$ (Jacobson Radical) iff it is not an isomorphism.
My ideas: Im $\phi$ is a projective Module, so $\phi:P \to Im \ \phi$ splits, hence $\phi$ has to be a monomorphism. That means, $P$ is a submodule of $Q$. Assume $P$ is not contained in $rad Q$. Then use $Q/rad Q$ is simple, thus $ Q = rad Q + P$ and Nakayama implies $P = Q$. Contradiction.
